# how to return array from linq?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am writing linq query to get data from multiple tables. I am trying to get array of objects as below.

```
   processobject retObj = new processobject();
 retObj =(from c in entityObject.NCT_Process
    join user in entityObject.NCT_UserRegistration on c.createdUserId equals user.User_Id
     join file in entityObject.NCT_FileUpload on c.iconfileId equals file.upld_ID 
    join templObj in entityObject.NCT_Templates on c.ID equals templObj.processId
   where c.processid == "10"
   select new processobject
    {
    id = c.ID,
    code = c.code,
    flochartContent = c.flowchartContent,
    //arrayofTemplates array i want to return
    }
    );
    public class processobject
    {
    public templatesObject[] arrayofTemplates { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string flochartContent { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    }
```

In the above query i have written condition where `c.processid == "10"`. so there are multiple records exists in `NCT_Templates` with `processid` 10. I want to return array with all those records. I have created array as below in my custom class.
I have this query

```
 processobject retObj = new processobject();
retObj = (from c in entityObject.NCT_Process
                                  join user in entityObject.NCT_UserRegistration on c.createdUserId equals user.User_Id
                                  join file in entityObject.NCT_FileUpload on c.iconfileId equals file.upld_ID
                                  into filesObjFirst
                                  from wt1 in filesObjFirst.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                  join templObj in entityObject.NCT_Templates on c.ID equals templObj.processId
                                  into filesObj
                                  from wt in filesObj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                  where c.ID == dbObject.ID
                                  select new processobject
                                  {

                                      id = c.ID,
                                      code = c.code,
                                      flochartContent = c.flowchartContent,
                                      name = c.name,
                                      parentId = c.parentId,
                                      projectId = c.projectId,
                                      objectives = c.objectives,
                                      displayOrder = c.dispalyOrder,
                                      iconFileId = c.iconfileId,
                                      level = c.level,
                                      iconFileobj = new iconFile
                                      {
                                          id = wt1.upld_ID,
                                          name = wt1.fileName,
                                          url = wt1.filePath
                                      },
                                      description = c.description,
                                      startCriteria = c.startCriteria,
                                      endCriteria = c.endCriteria,
                                      reporting = c.reporting,
                                      output = c.output,
                                      kpi = c.kpi,
                                      procedureHistory = c.procedureHistory,
                                      role = c.role,
                                      duration = c.duration,
                                      owner = c.owner,
                                      visibility = true,
                                      createdUserId = c.createdUserId,
                                  }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I have this one more query

```
 templatesObject[] templatesobject = (from c in entityObject.NCT_Templates
                                                             where c.processId == dbObject.ID
                                                             join file in entityObject.NCT_FileUpload on c.templateFileId equals file.upld_ID
                                                             into filesObjFirst
                                                             from wt1 in filesObjFirst.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                             select new templatesObject
                                                             {
                                                                 id = c.id,
                                                                 title = c.title,
                                                                 version = c.version,
                                                                 visible = c.visibility,
                                                                 filesObj = new iconFileTemplate()
                                                                 {
                                                                     id = wt1.upld_ID,
                                                                     url = wt1.filePath,
                                                                     name = wt1.fileName
                                                                 }
                                                             }).ToArray();
```

Inside `arrayofTemplates` I want to store records of `NCT_Templates`.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A `.ToArray()` will do the job after your query.

```
   processobject retObj = new processobject();
 retObj =(from c in entityObject.NCT_Process
    join user in entityObject.NCT_UserRegistration on c.createdUserId equals user.User_Id
     join file in entityObject.NCT_FileUpload on c.iconfileId equals file.upld_ID 
    join templObj in entityObject.NCT_Templates on c.ID equals templObj.processId
   where c.processid == "10"
   select new processobject
    {
    id = c.ID,
    code = c.code,
    flochartContent = c.flowchartContent,
    //arrayofTemplates array i want to return
    }
    );

var arr = retObj.ToArray();
```

**Update**

I Recommend you use `ICollection` instead of an Array. since you wanted the array the solution is explained above, but its more understandable if you use `ICollection`:

```
public class processobject
{
public ICollection<processobject> processobject{ get; set; }
public int id { get; set; }
public string flochartContent { get; set; }
public string code { get; set; }
}
```

then create a collection and pass it to the property like:

```
var list = retObj.ToList();
```

**Update**

Since the Array in the json object returns properties, i recommend you create another model. and pass the value directly to an object of this class. like below:

```
public class processobject
{
public templateFileId templateFileId{ get; set; }
public int id { get; set; }
public string flochartContent { get; set; }
public string code { get; set; }
}

public class templateFileId
{
  public int id {get; set;}
  public string url {get; set;}
  public string name {get; set;}
  public int created {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question. I do not know how can i assign values to the properties. I have posted sample object above.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole updated :), remember if the array returns more than one set of data u need to use ICollection as above

Comment: Thanks for your time. templateFileId will be having more than one rows in my case. How can i assign values to properties of templateFileId. For example i have written id = c.id, title = c.title,version = c.version so like this how can i assign values to url,name etc

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole In your query. you can do a select based on TemplatefileId, assign the data to new class like : `new templateFileId { id = c.Id, url = c.Url, name = c.Name, created = c.Created } `

Comment: already i have  select new processobject how can i add new templateFileId

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole tell me first where do u getting this object is it from database or a webservice?

Comment: i have posted actual queries above. Both queries working fine. I am trying to combine this queries. i want templatesobject inside of first query result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137218/discussion-between-valkyriee-and-niranjan-godbole).